# wpf threads error

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

```
Thread thread;
OtherMonitor monitor;
public void StartRecieveData()
{
        System.Net.IPEndPoint iep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 999);
        UdpClient client = new UdpClient(iep);
        client.EnableBroadcast = true;           
        string data = null;
        while (true)
        {                
            byte[] byteData = client.Receive( ref iep);
            data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
            InsertDataToBase(data);
            UpdateSecondMonitor(data);
        }
}

private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
 monitor = new OtherMonitor();
 monitor.Show();
 thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(StartRecieveData));
 thread.IsBackground = true;
 thread.Start();           
}

InsertDataToBase(data) //  function  inserting record into Database
UpdateSecondMonitor(data) //- opened window on the second monitor, which  should be updated
{
  monitor.UpdateGrid();
}
```

and error when trying udate grid on the monitor window:
The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it

I try:

```
   //thread = new System.Threading.Thread(
   //         new System.Threading.ThreadStart(
   //         delegate()
   //         {
   //          races.Dispatcher.Invoke(
   //            System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
   //                 new Action(delegate { StartRecieveData(); }));
   //         }
```

I don't know how to update data in the 'monitor' window.
someone maybe know??

Comment: You *can* have multiple UI threads in WPF, but it's unusual to want to do so. Why not just show all your UI on the main thread like a normal app?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `UpdateSecondMonitor(data);` use

```
this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action<string>((data)=>UpdateSecondMonitor(data)));
```

to make sure the UI is updated on the correct thread.